# Webfilter double urlpattern definiton required?

Tags: tomcat, servlet-filters, url-pattern

I am using Tomcat 7 in my JSF-Project and I am working with Webfilters

I have following problem: When I define a Webfilter like below, Tomcat starts without problems:

```
@WebFilter(filterName="isLoggedInFilter", urlPatterns={"/pages/*"})
public class IsLoggedInFilter implements Filter {...}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>isLoggedInFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when i leave the url-pattern in the web-xml empty (because I don't want to specify the url-pattern twice the same, tomcat fails to start and gives me following exception:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid   in filter mapping**

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>isLoggedInFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern />
</filter-mapping>
```

Do I really have to define the url pattern twice?? If i don't specify it in the Webfilter Annotation, it tells me to specify either  or

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you declare the mapping in the web.xml, since it's already defined by the annotation?

Comment: @JBNizet: annotation based mapping doesn't support ordering.

Comment: Thats true, i need ordered filters.